# Angular Observer if user is logged in or not

Tags: angular, authentication, local-storage

My login.component is setting a localstorage item with a token. I would like my nav.component always to know about it and react whenever the token is there or deleted, and I would like my Auth to hold the Observable. I would like my nav.component to subscribe to the Observable. I think that i'm almost there but need som last guidance. As of now it does not change any properties in my nav.

As of now I am not able to observe any changes made to localstorage. It always return false. I can set the loggedIn to true and the my nav will react to that, so i guess it is something to do with the Observable in the Auth.

This is my app.component that holds the nav.

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My nav-component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  public isLoggedIn: Boolean;

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService, private router: Router
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.isLoggedIn().subscribe(
      mes =>{
        this.isLoggedIn = mes;
      }
    );
  }
  handleAction(){
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
  }
  logoutUser(){
    this.auth.logoutUser();
  }
}
```

And my auth.service:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Subject, Observable, EMPTY, throwError,} from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {  
  private apiroot = "My api root";
  public loggedIn = false;
  logger = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router : Router
  ) { }
  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.logger.asObservable();
  }
  loggedInStatus(){
    //Used for guards
    return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
  registerUser(user){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiroot + "register", user)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
  }
  resetPassword(user){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiroot + 'resetpassword', user)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
  }
  loginUser(user){
    // this.loggedIn = true;
    this.logger.next(this.loggedIn);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiroot + "login", user)
  }
  logoutUser(){
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.loggedIn = false;
    this.logger.next(this.loggedIn);
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, the only instruction that sets `loggedIn` to true is commented out.

Comment: In my nav.component?

Comment: When you do `this.logger.next(this.loggedIn);`, the value of `this.loggedIn` is false, is it not?

Comment: Yes, true. I allways return false.

Comment: So as it stands, `this.isLoggedIn` within your nav component will never be set to true

Comment: True, so I guess I would like Login to tell Auth that user is logged in, so that Auth can tell Nav that user is logged in